# Why do we need $a:\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be positive here?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

This is exercise 6.1 from the book Foundations of Machine Learning:

> Let $K: \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a PDS kernel, and let $a:
> \mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a positive function. Show that the kernel $K'$ defined for all $x, y \in \mathcal{X}$ by $K'(x,y)=\frac{K(x,y)}{a(x)a(y)}$ is a PDS kernel.

I was able to show this by considering a feature map $\Phi$ associated to $K$ and noticing that for $\mathbf{c}\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\} \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ we have
$$\mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{K'}\mathbf{c}=\sum_{i,j}\frac{c_ic_jK(x_i,x_j)}{a(x_i)a(x_j)} =\left\|\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{c_i \Phi(x_i)}{a(x_i)}\right\|_{\mathbb{H}}^2 \geq 0$$
which along with symmetry proves that $K'$ is a PDS kernel. However, nowhere in this proof did I use the fact that $a$ is a positive function (only non-zero for the definition of $K'$ to make sense).

Is my solution wrong or can the assumption be relaxed from positive to non-zero?

**EDIT:** A kernel function $K: \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ is called PDS if for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\{x_1,\dots, x_m\} \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ the matrix $\mathbf{K}=[K(x_i, x_j)]_{i,j \in [m]}$ is symmetric positive semi-definite

Comment: Technically speaking, a kernel $K$ does not necessarily need to have a feature space dot product representation $K(x, y) = \langle \Phi(x), \Phi(y) \rangle$. For this general case, you do need $a$ to be positive.  Otherwise, your solution/challenge is correct.

Comment: What is PDS Kernel? Is this alternative notation for PSD (positive semi definite)?

Comment: @Zhanxiong I have edited my question to include the definition of PDS kernel. Under this definition, it can be proven that such Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$ always exists that further has the reproducing property.

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me. Indeed, in other places this exercise is stated without this unnecessary assumption. See e.g. Paulsen, Raghupathi: " An Introduction to the Theory of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces", Exercise 2.2

Comment: @gg Thanks for your input. I thought I was missing something since most exercises do not impose unnecessary assumptions.